# SQL percentage grouped by date

Tags: sql

I need help with writing an SQL query, as I have the following situation:
I need to calculate the percentages of each type of object received in a factory grouped by date. There are only 2 types and for each type I need to show the percentage corresponding to it relative to that exact date and time. The table should looks like this (I couldn't draw it perfectly but I included the percentage column for clearer view of what I mean).

[image]

The SQL I tried writing for the percentage column looks like this but I know it's not good:

```
CASE 
WHEN cond1
THEN (SELECT COUNT(NrOfObjects) as ObjectsWithCondition1 FROM tbl
      WHERE cond1) / ((SELECT COUNT(IDObject) AS ObjectsWithCondition1 FROM tbl
      WHERE cond1)+(SELECT COUNT(IDObject) AS ObjectsWithCondition2 FROM tbl
      WHERE cond2) 
      );
WHEN cond2
THEN (SELECT COUNT(NrOfObjects) as ObjectsWithCondition2 FROM tbl
      WHERE cond2) / ((SELECT COUNT(IDObject) AS ObjectsWithCondition2 FROM tbl
      WHERE cond2)+(SELECT COUNT(IDObject) AS ObjectsWithCondition1 FROM tbl
      WHERE cond1) 
      );
```

cond1 is for example "tbl.Type='Type1'

Any help will be great, thanks!

Example
(Input:)2 objects of type 1 brought at 1/4/22 10:00 => percentage is 66% for this entry(this is the desired output)
(Input:)1 object of type 2 at 1/4/22 10:00 =>percentage is 34% for this entry(this is the desired output)

//for a different date
(Input:) 1 object of type 1 brought at 1/4/22 11:00 => percentage is 50% for this entry (this is the desired output)

(Input:)1 object of type 2 brought at 1/4/22 11:00 => percentage is 50% for this entry (this is the desired output)

Comment: Would be good if you posted a data sample + expected output as *text* (much less painful to do for both you and anyone willing to answer!)

Comment: What's your DBMS ? What's your "error" ? And please, post your sample data & desired output.

Comment: I added the sample data and output, which is also presented in the table.

Answer (score 0):

There might be more elegant ways to write it depending on what DBMS you're using, but a fairly generic solution is to generate a couple of Common Table Expressions to hold counts grouped by type and date and by just date, and then build a final expression that joins them and expresses percentage as the ratio of by type to date total

```
with cteData as ( --This is just the data to prove it works, not part of the solution
    SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES ('2021-12-30 10:00 AM', 'Type 1', 'Dingle') 
        , ('2021-12-30 10:00 AM', 'Type 1', 'Dongle') 
        , ('2021-12-30 10:00 AM', 'Type 1', 'Dangle') 
        , ('2021-12-30 10:00 AM', 'Type 2', 'Bit') 
        , ('2021-12-30 10:00 AM', 'Type 2', 'Bot') 
        , ('2021-12-30 11:00 AM', 'Type 1', 'Dongle') 
        , ('2021-12-30 11:00 AM', 'Type 1', 'Dangle') 
        , ('2021-12-30 11:00 AM', 'Type 2', 'Bit') 
    ) as ValType(RecDate, ObjType, ObjName)
), cteDateCounts as ( --The solution starts here - get totals for each date
    SELECT RecDate, count(*) as DateCount FROM cteData GROUP BY RecDate
), cteTypeCount as ( --Now get the count of each type grouped by date
    SELECT RecDate, ObjType, count(*) as TypeCount FROM cteData GROUP BY RecDate, ObjType
) --The percent is just the total for a type divided by the total of all types on that date
--Note that a little creative casting is needed to keep SQL from dropping precision too soon
SELECT T.*, convert(int, 100 * (convert(float,T.TypeCount) / D.DateCount)) as TypePercent
FROM cteTypeCount as T 
    INNER JOIN cteDateCounts as D on T.RecDate = D.RecDate
```

Gives result

| RecDate | ObjType | TypeCount | TypePercent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-30 10:00 AM | Type 1 | 3 | 60 |
| 2021-12-30 10:00 AM | Type 2 | 2 | 40 |
| 2021-12-30 11:00 AM | Type 1 | 2 | 66 |
| 2021-12-30 11:00 AM | Type 2 | 1 | 33 |

NOTE: This groups by EXACT date and time. Depending on how your actual data is formatted, you might want to apply a step before the grouping that converts exact times to the nearest hour or whatever.